# How can I show the build and application version in quarkus application?

Tags: quarkus

Like Spring Boot Actuator Info endpoint, is it possible to show the application version and build info in quarkus application?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything like that in Quarkus at the moment. You'll probably have to create the properties in your application.properties and add them in the responses, for example.

[Configuring Your Application - Quarkus guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/config)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Micrometer Metrics library. Might not have all the metrics and info you are looking for, but you will get plenty of information.

Micrometer - https://quarkus.io/guides/micrometer 
SmallRye Health - https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-health - Health Check
Build Info(Maven Goal) - https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling#project-info

I guess these all should help.

Comment: actually  I mean  ,for eg :in spring boot  if i use localhost:8080/actuator/info will get all details like project build and version etc. ref : https://springhow.com/spring-boot-actuator-info-endpoint/

Comment: I'm Afraid you will have to write such endpoints on your own to get the required details. I  checked quarkus guide thoroughly and couldn't find anything. Besides from the link - https://dzone.com/articles/spring2quarkus-spring-boot-to-quarkus-migration , I'm aware that other people reached the same conclusion as well. Refer to Info endpoint.